# Perl regex to change date format

Tags: regex, perl, date, format, replace

I'm totally new to Perl, and I need to get a small find and replace done to change the date format in a set of large file.
The files have dates in the format: dd.mm.yyyy
and I need to change them to: mm-dd-yyyy

How do I do this with perl?

I have a basic code to read through the files in a directory and write to an output file, I'll need to have my replace logic in-between the while loop (if i'm not wrong!).

```
#!c:/perl64/bin/perl.exe

#loop around a directory
@files = <C:/perl64/data/*>;

# loop around files
foreach $file (@files) {

#Read File
open READ, $file or die "Cannot open $read for read :$!";

#Output File
$fname=substr($file, rindex($file,"/")+1,length($file)-rindex($file,"/")-1);
$write="C:/perl64/output/$fname";

open WRITE, ">$write" or die "Cannot open $write for write :$!";

#Loop Around file
while (<READ>) {

           # TO DO: Change date format from dd.mm.yyyy to mm-dd-yyyy

           #Write to ourput file
           print WRITE "$_";

}

}
```

Regards,

Anand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the substitution operator `s///`:

```
while (<READ>) {
    s/(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})/$2-$1-$3/;
    print WRITE "$_";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene! The substitution works, but with one issue. The substitution happens only for the first occurence of dd.mm.yyyy in each line. The second and further occurrences in a line are not substituted. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Ahand: `s///` replaces only the first occurrence of the pattern by default. You can use the `/g` modifier to replace all occurrences: `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/g`

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I just figured that out with some google search and it solved the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple script that will take optional arguments for input and output directories.

The use of `opendir` instead of a glob will save you some trouble cleaning up the file names.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $indir = shift || "C:/perl64/data";
my $outdir = shift || "C:/perl64/output";

opendir(my $in, $indir);

while (readdir $in) {
    next unless -f;
    open my $infile, '<', $_;
    open my $outfile, '>', $outdir . "/" . $_;
    while (<$infile>) {
        s/([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{4})/$2-$1-$3/g; 
        print $outfile $_;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks TLP. But for some reason there is no output file when I run this. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: The script worked when I tried it, so it's pretty hard to say why it's not working on your end. Probably has to do with how you are passing the command line args.